# rotating a linked list

Tags: python, list, rotation

While practicing for my final I ran into this question of rotating a linked list. So if the linked list was`[3,6,2,7]` it would be `[6,2,7,3]` after the call. However when coding it I managed to reverse it by accident. Can anyone see my mistake and maybe point me in the right direction. After my code runs I get `[7,2,6,3]`. Also, as you can see I had to implement linked lists as dictionarys

```
def rotateLinkedList(lis):
    ptr = lis
    temp = ptr['data']
    while ptr['next'] == None:
        temp = ptr['data']['next']
        ptr = ptr['next']
    return lis
```

Answer (score 0):

For rotating the list you do not need re-implement linked list and can use what there is.  So for the rotation you can use the  standard FIFO approach: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues

and to append the removed item to the end of the list.

You can also use:

```
l = [3,6,2,7]
rotated = l.append(l.pop(0))
```

Btw, the list in CPython is implemented as the array of pointers. Nice insight is here: https://www.quora.com/How-are-Python-lists-implemented-internally and here: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/

Implementing linked list as the data structure is quite low level. As you can typically get the similar outcome with other means in Python - list, deque.

Something else is if you need to re-implement linked list for the educational purposes.

Comment: Most Python implementations implement `list` as some sort of vector or array, not as a linked list.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - indeed the list in CPython is implemented as the array of pointers. Nice insight is here: https://www.quora.com/How-are-Python-lists-implemented-internally. My point was that for rotating the list you do not need re-implement linked list and can use what there is. Updating my answer.